# Trying to concat multiples authors into fb articles shares

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$authors = $newsitem->get_item_authors();
        if( !empty( $authors ) ){
            $facebook_author .= ',' .get_user_meta( $authors[0]->ID, 'eco_author_social_profile', true );
        }
```

Trying to concat multiple authors in a fb share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with implode

```
<?php

$authors = $newsitem->get_item_authors();
$facebook_authors = array()
if( !empty( $authors ) ){
    $facebook_authors[] = get_user_meta( $authors[0]->ID, 'eco_author_social_profile', true );
}
$facebook_author = implode(",", $facebook_authors);

?>
```

You can also do this with your code

```
$authors = $newsitem->get_item_authors();
if( !empty( $authors ) ){
    $facebook_author .= ',' .get_user_meta( $authors[0]->ID, 'eco_author_social_profile', true );
}
$facebook_author = ltrim($facebook_author, ",");
```